# DATE_TRUNC combined with MAX statement

Tags: sql, oracle, max

Let's say i have these columns in a table:

- name
- id
- startdate
- enddate

I want to select all the names that have the same enddate for every day.
Problem is, some names have the same id, meaning I need to select the max id.

**for the max id i have the following:**

select max(id), name, startdate , enddate
from mytable
group by id,  name, startdate , enddate;

**For the counting per day I have the following: (2 queries that work)**

select enddate, count(id) from mytable
group by enddate
order by enddate asc;

**OR**

select
date_trunc('day', enddate) m,
count(enddate) enddates_per_Day
from mytable
group by m
order by m;

| m (date) | end_per_Day |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-11-01 | 3 |
| 2022-11-02 | 4 |

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need the `having` clause.

```
  SELECT name, TRUNC (enddate) enddate, COUNT (*) end_per_day
    FROM mytable
GROUP BY name, TRUNC (enddate)
  HAVING COUNT (*) > 1;
```

If you also need the ID, one option is to use a correlated subquery:

```
  SELECT (SELECT MAX (a.id)
            FROM mytable a
           WHERE a.name = b.name) id,
         b.name,
         TRUNC (b.enddate) enddate,
         COUNT (*) end_per_day
    FROM mytable b
GROUP BY b.name, TRUNC (b.enddate)
  HAVING COUNT (*) > 1;
```